# Django verification email

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I have a Django app deployed on Pythonanywhere. Everything works as expected except for the verification emails.When a new user registers, he should receive a verification email, but Django doesn't send it until the admin panel is reloaded. All other emails(welcome emails, contact form emails) are sent without issue. When I test locally on my laptop verification emails are sent instantly. I am using django-email-verification and emails are sent through gmail.

views.py

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'common/register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('index')

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(commit=False)
        user_email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        user_username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        user_password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(username=user_username, email=user_email, password=user_password)

        user.is_active = False
        send_email(user)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('email sent'))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: it could be some Pythonanywhere limitation

Comment: could you share the function `send_email`?

Comment: send_mail is part of django-email-verification library(https://github.com/LeoneBacciu/django-email-verification).

Comment: If you run it on a free account on PythonAnywhere you have limited internet access. See https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers/

Comment: Yes, i am using a free account. The email server configuration settings are made as per the requirements of Pythonanywhere. In all other cases when sending mail is required, like welcome emails, contact form emails everything is working as expected. Only verification emails on user registration are sent when i manually refresh user page in admin panel.

Comment: My guess would be that send_email does not send emails to inactive users. Reloading the admin page will reset the active start of the user object (because you are not saving it after you set the user to inactive), so the email would then be sent

Comment: That's not the problem. This application was deployed to AWS and everything worked as expected.